# validateDOMNesting(...): <td> cannot appear as a child of <tbody>. even the Structure is ok

Tags: reactjs, html-table

[image]

The structure is ok but I do get this error

[image]

But I dont have any `<td>` inside `<tbody>` only `<td>`s inside `<tr>`

my code is

```html
<table className="min-w-full divide-y divide-gray-200 ">
                                <thead className="bg-gray-100">
                                <tr>
                                    <th
                                        scope="col"
                                        className="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                                        <input
                                            onChange={(e) => {
                                                setAllChecked(!allChecked);
                                                setData(data.map(item => {
                                                    return {...item, isChecked: !allChecked}
                                                }))
                                                if (allChecked) {
                                                    setSelectedRows([])
                                                } else if (!allChecked) {
                                                    setSelectedRows(data);
                                                }
                                            }}
                                            checked={allChecked}
                                            id="remember-me"
                                            name="remember-me"
                                            type="checkbox"
                                            className="h-4 w-4 text-red-600 focus:ring-red-500 border-gray-300 rounded"
                                        />
                                    </th>
                                    <th
                                        scope="col"
                                        className="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider"
                                    >
                                        Product Name / Product id
                                    </th>
                                    <th
                                        scope="col"
                                        className="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider"
                                    >
                                        Product Category
                                    </th>
                                    <th
                                        scope="col"
                                        className="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider"
                                    >
                                        Brand
                                    </th>
                                    <th
                                        scope="col"
                                        className="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider"
                                    >
                                        Price
                                    </th>
                                    <th
                                        scope="col"
                                        className="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider"
                                    >
                                        Stock
                                    </th>
                                    <th
                                        scope="col"
                                        className="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider"
                                    >
                                        Status
                                    </th>
                                    <th scope="col" className="relative px-6 py-3">
                                        <span className="sr-only">Action</span>
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody className="bg-white divide-y divide-gray-200">
                                {data.length > 0 ? <>
                                    {data.map((product) => (
                                        <tr
                                            className={`${data.indexOf(product) % 2 === 0 ? 'bg-gray-50' : 'bg-white'}`}
                                            key={product.id}>
                                            <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500">
                                                <input
                                                    onChange={() => {
                                                        setData(data.map((item) => {
                                                            if (item.id === product.id) {
                                                                item.isChecked = !item.isChecked;
                                                            }
                                                            return item;
                                                        }));
                                                        setSelectedRows(data.filter((item) => item.isChecked));
                                                    }}
                                                    checked={product.isChecked}
                                                    id="remember-me"
                                                    name="remember-me"
                                                    type="checkbox"
                                                    className="h-4 w-4 text-red-600 focus:ring-red-500 border-gray-300 rounded"
                                                />
                                            </td>

                                            <td className="px-6 pl-2 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                                                <div className="flex items-center">
                                                    <div className="ml-4">
                                                        <div
                                                            className="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">{product.name.length > 20 ? product.name.slice(0, 20) + '...' : product.name}</div>
                                                        <div className="text-sm text-gray-500">{product.id}</div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                                                <div className="flex items-center">
                                                    <div className="ml-4">
                                                        <div
                                                            className="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">{product.category}</div>
                                                        <div
                                                            className="text-sm text-gray-500">{product.mainProductCategory}</div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                                                <div className="text-sm text-gray-900">{product.brand}</div>
                                            </td>

                                            <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500">$ {product.price}</td>
                                            <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500">{product.stock}</td>
                                            <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                                                {product.isPublished ? <>
                                                    <span
                                                        className="px-2 inline-flex text-xs leading-5 font-semibold rounded-full bg-green-100 text-green-800">Published</span></>
                                                    : <>
                                                    <span
                                                        className="px-2 inline-flex text-xs leading-5 font-semibold rounded-full bg-red-100 text-red-800">Not Published</span>
                                                    </>}
                                            </td>

                                            <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-right text-sm font-medium">
                                                <span className="relative z-0 inline-flex shadow-sm rounded-md">
                                                <button
                                                    onClick={(x) => {
                                                        changePublishedStatus(product.id, !product.isPublished)
                                                    }}
                                                    type="button"
                                                    className={`relative inline-flex items-center  py-2 rounded-l-md border border-gray-300 bg-white text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:z-10 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-red-500 focus:border-red-500 ${product.isPublished ? 'px-4' : 'px-6'}`}
                                                >
                                                    {product.isPublished ? 'Unpublish' : 'Publish'}
                                                </button>
                                                <button
                                                    type="button"
                                                    className="-ml-px relative inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 border border-gray-300 bg-white text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:z-10 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-red-500 focus:border-red-500"
                                                >
                                                    Edit
                                                </button>
                                                <button
                                                    onClick={() => {
                                                        deleteProduct(product.id)
                                                    }}
                                                    type="button"
                                                    className="-ml-px relative inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 rounded-r-md border border-gray-300 bg-white text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:z-10 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-red-500 focus:border-red-500 "
                                                >
                                                    Delete
                                                </button>
                                                </span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    ))}
                                </> : <>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500">
                                        <span
                                            className="inline-flex items-center px-2.5 py-0.5 rounded-md text-sm font-medium bg-red-100 text-red-800">
                                            No results found. Please refine your search or add Products.
                                        </span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </>}
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

how to fix this

Comment: Restart your IDE and see if the error is gone. My linter sometimes hangs itself too.

Comment: DId but dosent seem to change the error

Comment: And restarted your dev-server?

Comment: yes. even after computer restart the problem persists

Comment: remove parts of the content to narrow down the section that causes it. And keep in mind that you might look at the wrong file.